# Images not appearing in Facebook's share link tool

Tags: html, facebook, image

I am having an intermittent issue the Facebook share link function does not pull the the link image from the page. This is happening consistently intermittently, that is, it keeps happening but not for a consistent page, image, style, etc. I can't find any pattern. Pages won't work, and then they will. Most pages work fine at the first attempt, but maybe 5% fail.

Each time it happens I check the URL in the Facebook debug tool, and it finds the article image without problem. Often, after I use the debug tool and then try to share the link again the image is found by Facebook.

The site uses Open Graph tags that check out with the Facebook debug tool.

Here is one example page:

http://zujava.com/must-have-school-supplies

Are there other factors that impact whether an image is pulled along with a URL in Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours. So on the initial go unless you like the page or send it through the debugger, the image (and other meta data) will not appear.

Read more at

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo and
- [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)